# Java 8 Stream find objects in list that match some properties

Tags: java-8, stream, java-stream

Let's say I have the next list

```
List<MyData> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyData("id1", "name1", "secondName1", "phone1", "address1");
list.add(new MyData("id2", "name2", "secondName1", "phone2", "address2");
list.add(new MyData("id3", "name3", "secondName3", "phone1", "address1");
list.add(new MyData("id4", "name4", "secondName4", "phone4", "address4");
```

Using Java8 streams, I want to find in my list which items have the same phone and same address.

I've seen in this forum a lot of solutions to reduce lists filtering only by one property, but I need to match **two or more properties**.

Comment: Why do you think filtering by different numbers of properties somehow makes your problem different?

Comment: Some of the solutions I found collect grouping by one property, or use an auxiliar `Set` with the property to match as the key, and the object as the value. I cannot use those solutions as soon as I have more than one property.

Comment: If you want grouping, you will need a compound property, and all the rest is the same.

Comment: Using a compound property, or even a wrapper overriding the equals method with `.distinct` would work, but I wanted to know if there is another elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: so you want unique entries basically by phone and address?

Comment: A List is a poor man's compound class. It implements equals() and hashCode() properly. But it's much cleaner to define a real ContactInformation class, containing phone and address, and to group by ContactInformation.

Comment: Yes, list even allows compound to work over property set that is only known at runtime, like if you give user the choice of custom groupings.

Comment: @Eugene yes, the solution in this example will obtain a list containing the first and the third objects.

Comment: @JB Nizet, that's the solution I had in mind, but I wanted to know if it could be possible to get the same result without extra classes. In the real example I have to match 5 properties, and depending on the user case they could increase or decrease.

Comment: I already answered to that question. use a List to store the properties values, in order.

Comment: @JB Nizet, now I see what you mean, I didn't understand you completely, that should work, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
 list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            x -> Arrays.asList(x.getPhone(), x.getAddress()),
                            HashMap::new,
                            Collectors.toList()),
                    map -> {
                        map.values().removeIf(x -> x.size() == 1);
                        return map.values();
                    }));
```

Comment: And that works, I see you are using lists as JB Nizet suggested before. Thanks!

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner because those would be the entries that dont have duplicates

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner you had me thinking for a while here... Federico not understanding this? :) Will do! Thank u